# A query or code solution for getting all rows where a column matches (x AND y AND z)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically, we know that SQL IN is used to replace many OR conditions (x OR y OR z). But in this case I need a query, or a code solution to select all rows that contain (x AND y AND z). Something like http://www.mobile.de/ is using. On their site, when searching for vehicles the more features you select the less results you get. So they're obviously not using IN in their query. A **really** simplified version of my database would be this.

Adverts table:

```
--------------
| id | title |
--------------
```

Features table:

```
---------------
| id | f_name |
---------------
```

AdvertsFeatures table:

```
-------------------------------
| id | advert_id | feature_id |
-------------------------------
```

For the features search filter I do a LEFT JOIN with the AdvertsFeatures table and apply the following WHERE clause:

```
WHERE feature_id IN (x, y, z)
```

Thus, the Adverts that have **any** of the selected features come up. But like I said, I need a query or a code solution that gets only the Adverts that have **all but not necessarily only** the selected features. A user can select any number of features from a total of around 40 features. That would be a lot of WHERE clause "AND"s, which I already have many of.

How do I go about doing this? It doesn't have to be SQL, it could be a code solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" query.  I like to solve these using aggregation and the `having` clause.  In your case, you can do it this way:

```
select advert_id
from AdvertsFeatures af
where feature_id in (x, y, z)
group by advert_id
having count(*) = 3;
```

Note that you need to change the `3` to be the number of items in the `in` list.  This also assumes that there are no duplicates in the `AdvertsFeatures` data (otherwise, you just use `count(distinct featureid)` in the `having` clause).

Comment: But doesn't this mean that the query will only get the Adverts that have **only** those selected features and none other. And I want my query to get me the Adverts that have **all but not necessarily only** the selected Features. Sorry if I wasn't clear in my original question.

Comment: @Alternatex . . . That is what this query does.  Features other than x, y, and z are not considered.

Comment: Oh.. I must've gotten confused somehow. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's query above can be used as an inline view to obtain the advert_id's. Then, you join these advert_id's with the AdvertFeatures table again to get all the adverts, as below:

```
SELECT af1.*
FROM AdvertsFeatures af1
INNER JOIN  
    (SELECT advert_id
    FROM AdvertsFeatures
    WHERE feature_id in (x, y, z)
    GROUP BY advert_id
    HAVING count(*) = 3;
) af2
ON af1.advert_id = af2.advert_id;
```